# Configuring the testtrack pro form

Tags: testtrack

we have a form in testtrack. it has a lot of fields. some of them are used on a daily basis and some of them are not needed and take a lot of space. 
is there a way to resize these fields? i can then add more fields and save the custom fields tab.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on whether you are referring to the built-in TestTrack fields or custom fields.

If your company does not use a specific built-in field, you could use field-level security options to hide that field from users. If it is a custom field, then you can just delete the field.

For custom fields you have several other options:

1. Multi-line custom fields do have a vertical size option which you can configure from the Edit Custom Fields window.
2. You can configure the location of the custom fields. Your location options consist of the main detail window (top part of the window) or the Custom field tab. You can also configure the order of these fields. The less commonly used custom fields should be pushed to the Custom field tab and/or pushed down in the order of custom fields.